# How to prevent access of pages in admin foldar from normal user in php?

Tags: php, directory, admin

I have pages in admin foldar. how to stop access of these pages from normal user.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I created a login form with admin role. as login successfull, both user and admin can access admin pages.

Comment: update your question with your own code that you already tried to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a .htaccess file (with a .htpasswd), so that the admins will have to be connected to access to the admin folder

Comment: you have to help him with his own code. he did not show you any code yet.